# Вычисление квадратного корня c помощью формулы Герона

Tags: математика, рекурсия, haskell

Стоит задача: Вычислить квадратный корень из любого числа с помощью формулы Герона. Не могу разобраться с "циклами" в haskell, нужна ваша помощь.

Comment: Если есть возможность возвести в дробную степерь, в чем смысл задания? И где вы тут рекурсию увидели?

Comment: Уже убрал рекурсию, изменил немного, задача изначально была не верно поставлена

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вопрос в том как реализованы "циклы" в haskell, то общеизвестно, что реализованы они через рекурсию.
Так, на примере итерационной формулы Герона `X(n+1) = 1/2*( X(n) + a/X(n))` можем написать функцию `sqrt_heron_iter` с рекурсией:

```
sqrt_heron_iter a xn = 
    sqrt_heron_iter a 1/2*(xn + a/xn)
```

Очевидно, что такая рекурсия будет бесконечной, и нам нужно предусмотреть условие выхода из неё. Таким условием может быть достигнутая достаточная точность решения.
То есть, разница между X(n) и X(n+1) должна быть меньше определённого малого числа, например, меньше 0.000000001.

```
sqrt_heron_iter a xn = 
    if abs(xn - ((xn + a/xn)/2) ) < 0.000000001 then xn else sqrt_heron_iter a ((xn + a/xn)/2)
```

А теперь условимся, что искать решение будем только в области действительных чисел, поэтому проверим, больше ли нуля `a`. Обернём функцию в такую, где будет только
один аргумент. И ещё немного сократим запись за счет введения дополнительного определения xn1 при помощи `let`

```
main = do
    let sqrt_a = sqrt_heron 2
    putStrLn $ "sqrt(2)=" ++ show sqrt_a
    let sqrt_a = sqrt_heron 3
    putStrLn $ "sqrt(3)=" ++ show sqrt_a
    let sqrt_a = sqrt_heron (-1)
    putStrLn $ "sqrt(-1)=" ++ show sqrt_a

sqrt_heron a = 
    if a < 0 then 
        (error "no answer in real numbers")
    else
        sqrt_heron_iter a ((a+1)/2)
sqrt_heron_iter a xn = 
    let
        xn1 = 1/2*(xn + a/xn)
    in
        if abs(xn - xn1) < 0.000000001 then xn1 else sqrt_heron_iter a xn1
```

Получим такой вывод в консоли:

```
sqrt(2)=1.414213562373095
sqrt(3)=1.7320508075688772

jdoodle: no answer in real numbers
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at jdoodle.hs:11:10 in main:Main
Command exited with non-zero status 1
```

Первые два вызова отработали успешно, а последний вызвал ошибку. Как и было запланировано.